# Rego - assign array to existing array

Tags: policy, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm getting a weird behavior in Rego and I wonder why does it happen.

[Link](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/bM4OR5pthC) to Rego Playground

When I create an empty array, and than assign to it new array, the count of the first array is still zero:

```
package play

x[{"msg": msg}]{
    c := []
    a := [1,2]
    b := [3,4]
    c = array.concat(a,b)
    count(c) > 0
    msg := "Length of c is greater than zero"
}
```

And the output is:

```
    {
    "x": []
}
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I get false in the line count(c)> 0?
2. How can I assign array to existing one? ( I need it because I have function that returns array and I'm trying to return the concatenation of 2 arrays. e.g.:

   func[{"msg": msg}] = c{
   a := [1,2]
   b := [3,4]
   c = array.concat(a,b)
   }

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rego values and variables are immutable, so there's no way to assign a new value to an already existing variable. Your example compiles due to using the [unification](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#unification) operator (`=`) rather than the assignment operator (`:=`).

In the example you provided, simply remove the first assignment:

```
package play

x[{"msg": msg}]{
    a := [1,2]
    b := [3,4]
    c := array.concat(a,b)
    count(c) > 0
    msg := "Length of c is greater than zero"
}
```